# Erlang: elegant tuple_to_list/1

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I'm getting myself introduced to Erlang by Armstrongs "Programming Erlang". One Exercise is to write a reeimplementation of the tuple_to_list/1 BIF. My solution seems rather inelegant to me, especially because of the helper function I use. Is there a more Erlang-ish way of doing this?

```
tup2lis({}) -> [];
tup2lis(T) -> tup2list_help(T,1,tuple_size(T)).

tup2list_help(T,Size,Size) -> [element(Size,T)];
tup2list_help(T,Pos,Size) -> [element(Pos,T)|tup2list_help(T,Pos+1,Size)].
```

Thank you very much for your ideas. :)

Comment: Make yourself aware which of the implementations below is tail-recursive.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having helper functions, often you need them and they are the best way of doing things. And don't be over concerned with tail-recursion, see http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listHandling.html#id64720

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think your function is ok, and more if your goal is to learn the language. 
As a matter of style, usually the base case when constructing lists is just the empty list [].
So I'd write

```
tup2list(Tuple) -> tup2list(Tuple, 1, tuple_size(Tuple)).

tup2list(Tuple, Pos, Size) when Pos =< Size ->  
    [element(Pos,Tuple) | tup2list(Tuple, Pos+1, Size)];
tup2list(_Tuple,_Pos,_Size) -> [].
```

you can write pretty much the same with list comprehension

```
[element(I,Tuple) || I <- lists:seq(1,tuple_size(Tuple))].
```

it will work as expected when the tuple has no elements,  as lists:seq(1,0) gives an empty list.

Comment: +1 for list comprehension. I like the usage of lists:seq. Feels a bit pythonian to me. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Your code is good and also idiomatic way how to make this sort of stuff. You can also build this list backward which in this case will be a little bit faster because of tail call but not significant.

```
tup2list(T) -> tup2list(T, size(T), []).

tup2list(T, 0, Acc) -> Acc;
tup2list(T, N, Acc) -> tup2list(T, N-1, [element(N,T)|Acc]).
```

Comment: Better to use  `tuple_size/1` instead of  `size/1`. See here: http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/commoncaveats.html

Answer (score 4):

I am attempting exercises from Joe Armstrong book, Here is what I came up with

```
my_tuple_to_list(Tuple) -> [element(T, Tuple) || T <- lists:seq(1, tuple_size(Tuple))].
```

Answer (score 2):

In [Erlang R16B](http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R16B.readme) you can also use [erlang:delete_element/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#delete_element-2) function like this:

```
tuple2list({}) -> [];
tuple2list(T) when is_tuple(T) ->
    [element(1, T) | tuple2list(erlang:delete_element(1, T))].
```

Comment: +1 for getting rid of the helper function and the need for counter and accumulator. I read that the speedup of tail-recursion vs. head-recursion in current versions is more a matter of processor-architecture* so I quit like this solution!
*http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html

Comment: -1 for a solution which creates a new tuple when an element is added to the list. Remember there is no mutable data in erlang and `erlang:delete_element/2` creates a new tuple!

Comment: @Zakum: You should read this myth demystification more carefully. _body-recursive list function and tail-recursive function that calls `lists:reverse/1` at the end will use exactly the same amount of memory_ Note the `lists:reverse/1` which mine version doesn't do. Mine tail recursive version definitely will be faster than body recursive [ppolv](http://stackoverflow.com/users/171116/ppolv)'s [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16222818/49197), no doubt. But when most tuples are small ti doesn't matter. But know the difference.

Comment: @rvirding If I understand the question correctly it was about **elegant** `tuple_to_list/1` not about most optimal one, because you can't beat [erlang:tuple_to_list/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#tuple_to_list-1) anyway.

Comment: @hdima True, but an elegant solution is not needlessly inefficient. IMAO.

Comment: The question is about a discussion on idiomatic erlang, which of course includes the readability vs. efficiency trade off. Insofar each of the examples was interesting! :)

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough I'm learning this right now using the same book by Joe Armstrong the second edition and Chapter 4 is about modules and functions which covers List Comprehension, Guards, Accumulators etc.  Anyways using this knowledge my solution is the code below :

```
-module(my_tuple_to_list).
-export([convert/1]).

convert(T) when is_tuple(T) -> [element(Pos,T) || Pos <- lists:seq(1,tuple_size(T))].
```

Most of the answers were already given in the same way mine just adds the Guard to ensure that a Tuple was given.

Answer (score 0):

Erlang 17.0, you should build list in natural order, solutions above is incorrect from the point of efficiency. Always add elements to the head of an existing list:

```
%% ====================================================================
%% API functions
%% ====================================================================
my_tuple_to_list({}) ->
    [];
my_tuple_to_list(Tuple) ->
   tuple_to_list_iter(1, size(Tuple), Tuple, [])
.
%% ====================================================================
%% Internal functions
%% ====================================================================
tuple_to_list_iter(N, N, Tuple, List) ->
    lists:reverse([element(N, Tuple)|List]);

tuple_to_list_iter(N, Tuplesize, Tuple, List) ->
    L = [element(N, Tuple)|List],
    tuple_to_list_iter(N + 1, Tuplesize, Tuple, L)    
.
```

Answer (score 0):

`mytuple_to_list(T) when tuple_size(T) =:= 0 -> [];
mytuple_to_list(T) -> [element(1, T)|mytuple_to_list(erlang:delete_element(1, T))].`